# Gather Installed Homebrew Packages as Ansible "facts" for MacOS

Tags: ansible

I can gather a list of Ansible facts on my MacOS system locally, using the following command:

```
ansible -m setup localhost
```

However, this list of facts doesn't provide a list of Homebrew packages that are installed, apparently.

If I run this command, I don't get any extra information about installed Homebrew packages either:

```
ansible -m homebrew localhost
```

All I get is the following output:

```
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": ""
}
```

**Question**: How can I extend Ansible to gather a list of *installed* Homebrew packages as Ansible "facts"?

Comment: Try [package_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/package_facts_module.html#package-facts-package-information-as-facts).

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, I just learned how to create Ansible custom facts via [this article](https://medium.com/@jezhalford/ansible-custom-facts-1e1d1bf65db8).

The solution is painfully simple. I created the following custom Ansible fact file under the path `/etc/ansible/facts.d/homebrew.fact`, which worked flawlessly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env pwsh
brew list -1 | ConvertTo-Json
```

Make sure that you make the `*.fact*` files executable as well, otherwise they won't be called by Ansible.

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/ansible/facts.d/homebrew.fact
```

**NOTE**: Requires PowerShell to be installed. `brew cask install powershell`

Comment: This "solution" is equivalent to running [command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html#command-execute-commands-on-targets) and [pipe](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/pipe.html#pipe-read-output-from-a-command) or [copy content](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/pipe.html#pipe-read-output-from-a-command). Without the necesity to install the script at remote host first.

Comment: @VladimirBotka Cool, I don't know enough about Ansible to know how that works. Could you post a solution with the steps that are required to make one of those modules work?

Comment: Sure. Take a look at the [example](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-examples/blob/master/examples/example-094/play1.yml) how to pipe the output of a command to variable.